# Dont know how to get submit value from radio with a VAR as name

Tags: javascript, html

I am creating a options form using radio button that is link to my database. the problem now is that to group the radio button the name is a var. But for me to get the post value i need to do request.body.name

so now my problem is that i cannot get the submited answer as i cannot get request.body a var as the input name

```
<form method="post" action="/marks">
        <%
        if(tls_question.length > 0){
            tls_question.forEach(function(data){
        %>
            <div class="b">
            <br>
            <input id="myInput" type="hidden" name="Question_no" value=<%= data.QUESTION_ID %>>
            <type="text"><%= data.CHAPTER_ID %><%= data.QUESTION_ID %>
                
                <div class="b">
                    <input type="radio" id="option1" value="1" name="option"
                    <label for="option1"><%= data.OPTION_1 %></label><br>
                    <input type="radio" id="option2" value="2" name="option"
                    <label for="option2"><%= data.OPTION_2 %></label><br>
                    <input type="radio" id="option3" value="3" name="option"
                    <label for="option3"><%= data.OPTION_3 %></label><br>
                    <br>
                </div>
            
            </div>
        <%
            });
        }
        else
        {
        %>
        <p>
            There is no data in data base.
        </p>
        <%
        }
        %>
        <input type="submit" value="submit">
    </form>


router.post("/marks", function(request, response, next){

var user_answer = request.body.option;
var question_no = request.body.Question_no;

console.log("u"+user_answer);
console.log("Q"+question_no);
if(user_answer && question_no){
    for(var qcount = 0; qcount < question_no.length; qcount++)
    {
        var _question = question_no[qcount];
        console.log(_question);

        con.query('SELECT * FROM tls_question.ftt_question WHERE QUESTION_ID = ?;', [_question], function(error, data){
            console.log("data"+data);
            if (data.length > 0){
                console.log("answer"+data[0].ANSWER);
                if(data[0].ANSWER == user_answer){
                    console.log("good")
                }
                else{
                } 
                response.end();
            }
        });
    }
}
else{
    response.send("No answer")
}
response.end();
```

});

the final product is to create 50 question with 3 options each that is link to my database and when they submit it will send back all the answer value in a array for me to mark them.

Comment: Do not post code as an image, post it as plain text in the question itself. Refer: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please post the code not an image..!

Answer (score 0):

First, create your HTML form with radio buttons and a submit button:

```
<form id="myForm">
    <input type="radio" name="group1" value="option1"> Option 1
    <input type="radio" name="group1" value="option2"> Option 2
    <input type="radio" name="group1" value="option3"> Option 3
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

The `querySelector` method is used to select the checked radio button within the group specified by the 'var' variable. The selected value is then retrieved and can be used for further processing.

```
document.getElementById("myForm").addEventListener("submit", function(event) {
event.preventDefault(); // Prevents the form from submitting the traditional way

var groupName = "group1"; // Variable containing the radio button group name
var selectedValue = document.querySelector('input[name="' + groupName + '"]:checked').value;

// Do something with the selected value, for example, log it to the console
console.log("Selected value: " + selectedValue);
});
```

Comment: is it possible to name the radio group with a variable instead? eg <input type="radio" name=variable x  value="option1"> because there is 50Question and i dont want to hard code all of them